Removing/Disabling the SQL: INSERT INTO statement in SQL Alchemy bulk insert
I am trying to insert more than 10K records in postgres sql database and using the SQL Alchemy bulk insert functionality using insert statement for this.
        insert_stmt = (
            insert(table)
            .values(records)
            .returning(getattr(table, primary_key))
        )

where table is table name and records is list of dictionaries.
While it works perfectly for happycases, in case of error scenarios in one of the records out of thousands, It logs the whole sql statement and is flooding the whole terminal with that one statement. It looks something like this
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type integer: "abc"
LINE 1: ...user', '2024-05-11T19:48:10.8932'::timestamp), ('abc', 'jo...
^
[SQL: INSERT INTO emp (user_id, first_name, last_name, created_by, create_time) VALUES (%(location_number_m0)s, %(user_id_m0)s, %(role_title_m0)s, %(first_name_m0)s, %(last_name_m0)s, %(created_by_m0)s, %(create_time_m0)s), (%(location_number_m1)s, %(user_id_m1)s, %(role_title_m1)s, %(first_name_m1)s, %(last_name_m1)s, %(created_by_m1)s, %(create_time_m1)s), (%(location_number_m2)s, %(user_id_m2)s, %(role_title_m2)s, %(first_name_m2)s, %(last_name_m2)s, %(created_by_m2)s, %(create_time_m2)s), (%(location_number_m3)s, %(user_id_m3)s, %(role_title_m3)s, %(first_name_m3)s, %(last_name_m3)s, %(created_by_m3)s, %(create_time_m3)s), (%(location_number_m4)s, %(user_id_m4)s, %(role_title_m4)s, %(first_name_m4)s, %(last_name_m4)s, %(created_by_m4)s, %(create_time_m4)s), (%(location_number_m5)s, %(user_id_m5)s, %(role_title_m5)s, %(first_name_m5)s, %(last_name_m5)s, %(created_by_m5)s, %(create_time_m5)s), (%(location_number_m6)s, %(user_id_m6)s, %(role_title_m6)s, %(first_name_m6)s, %(last_name_m6)s, %(created_by_m6)s, %(create_time_m6)s), (%(location_number_m7)s, %(user_id_m7)s, %(role_title_m7)s, %(first_name_m7)s, %(last_name_m7)s, %(created_by_m7)s, %(create_time_m7)s), (%(location_number_m8)s, %(user_id_m8)s, %(role_title_m8)s, %(first_name_m8)s, %(last_name_m8)s, %(created_by_m8)s, %(create_time_m8)s)]
How can i get rid of this statement, its difficult to navigate to the root cause which is above the  huge sql statement.
I tried to disable the logs using echo=False, echo_pool=False while create the engine. But its not working.
I tried setting the levels as well to INFO, ERROR, DEBUG, but didn't work as well
Also is there any way to print only the faulty row instead of the whole insert into statement?

You should validate the input before you put it into the SQL statement. And ignore the data that doesn’t meet the requirements

FrankHeikens's  comment is probably the best answer, another weaker alternative is to catch the exception and then log what you want.  You could also run smaller batches and catch the exceptions if you are having trouble determining the source/nature of the invalid data.  In general though suspect data should be validated before you put it in the DB because you might find out a year later you put bad data in and you can no longer fix it.

Thanks for the responses Frank & @IanWilson. Agreed the input needs to be validated. But since i am trying to insert around 500K of records and using batch size of 10K, the batch size can be any smaller for the solution to be performant. Also in huge dataset there can be invalid record for any reason and as the error comes before the Huge logged statement it very difficult to get to the exact root issue. I feel there should be way not to log the whole insert statement and log only the errored out record atleast.

For large amounts of data like yours, I would suggest using the copy protocol instead of insert statements. That is much faster. But you still have to do the validation of your data, that’s a step need anyway. See https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html

The performance is not an issue over here, troubleshooting is a challenge as even if the data is validated for datatype and other known aspects, it might fail because of some other reasons and navigating to root cause is difficult. BTW In SQLAlchemy 2.0 whats the best way to perform bulk inserts? insert statements, bulk_save_objects, copy commands, add_all or any other?

UPDATE - I utilized other way of performing the insert many statements as depicted in SQLAlchemy2.0 which uses something as session.execute(insert(table), records),
Using this it internally hides the statements and mentions the no.of characters hidden.
